# Show/Hide image button 3 second delay

Tags: javascript, html

This is the html part. What What I've done here is when the user clicks the button once, a showIMG function is called to show the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- showHide.html
      Uses showHide.js
      Illustrates visibility control of elements
     -->
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Visibility control </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "showHide.js" >
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "">
      <div id = "saturn"  style = "position: relative; 
           visibility: visible;">
        <img src = "../images/saturn.png" 
             alt = "(Pictures of Saturn)" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <br />
        <input type = "button"  value = "Toggle Saturn"
               onclick = "flipImag()" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file

```
// showHide.js
//   Illustrates visibility control of elements

// The event handler function to toggle the visibility 
//    of the images of Saturn 

function flipImag() {
  dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  

// Flip the visibility adjective to whatever it is not now 
 if (dom.visibility == "visible")
   dom.visibility = "hidden";
 else
   dom.visibility = "visible";
}
```

i want to click a button two times within three seconds, then  an image disappears, and when you click the button once, the image appears on the screen. 
i realise i have to use the toggle function and incorporate it with a timer but im not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout on first click and clearTimeout on the second click.

```
function checkClick(){
    if(window.flippingimage) clearTimeout(window.flippingimage);
    else window.flippingimage = setTimeout(3000, flipImag);
}
```

Then put this function on the onclick event of your button.

EDIT

Change your code to this code:

```
function flipImag() {
  dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  

// Flip the visibility adjective to whatever it is not now 
 if (dom.visibility == "visible")
   dom.visibility = "hidden";
 else
   dom.visibility = "visible";
}

function checkClick(){
    if(window.flippingimage) clearTimeout(window.flippingimage);
    else window.flippingimage = setTimeout(3000, flipImag);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Visibility control </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "showHide.js" >
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "">
      <div id = "saturn"  style = "position: relative; 
           visibility: visible;">
        <img src = "../images/saturn.png" 
             alt = "(Pictures of Saturn)" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <br />
        <input type = "button"  value = "Toggle Saturn"
               onclick = "checkClick()" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying. where do i add this?

Comment: Replace `flipImag()` in the `onclick` of the button with `checkClick()`. Add the above code to your Javascript file that has `flipImag` code in it.

Comment: i got the first part still lost on the second part. is it possible to explain the second part a bit more?